# textarea inside jQueryUI resizeable dialog

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, textarea, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jQueryUI resizeable [.dialog()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) with a `<textarea>` inside. My question is:

Is it possible to set somehow the height of the textarea to be 100% even after the testarea has been resized ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook into the resize event of the dialog box.

you'll want to clean up how it looks, but here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jp7TM/2858/